# how to read input from System variable while creating deployment through ARM template

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I am trying to deploy Ms Sql server by using Azure Cli and ARM template. When i execute the ARM template, it asks me for input parameters like `administratorLogin`, `administratorLoginPassword`, `serverName`. Below is the example:

```
root@649e67dacd8f:~/.jenkins/workspace/Terraform# az group deployment create --resource-group Arm-template --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-sql-logical-server/azuredeploy.json --verbose
Please provide string value for 'serverName' (? for help): chitender
Please provide string value for 'administratorLogin' (? for help): chitender
Please provide securestring value for 'administratorLoginPassword' (? for help):
```

So I need to input the parameters at runtime.

Now I am trying to automate it through Jenkins build project, so that I get `administratorLogin`, `administratorLoginPassword`, `serverName` input from user who is executing the Jenkins job and ARM template read this input through system variables instead of asking for input in runtime.

So i want to know is there any possible ways where I can enter the input variables through System global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following command to achieve this.
az group deployment create --resource-group Arm-template --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-sql-logical-server/azuredeploy.json --parameters administratorLogin=$administratorLogin administratorLoginPassword=$administratorLoginPassword serverName=$serverName --verbose

which $administratorLogin is the related variable.